# Subscribing dynamic number of subjects inside an observer class without using dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, design-patterns, embedded

I am trying to implement an observer design pattern to accommodate a case where I could subscribe notifications from the specific sensors every time their values are read.

So I came up with a design where I have a `Notification` class as an observer with respective `Sensor` class(es) as Subjects.

When the `Notification` class is instantiated, the passed-in subject subscribes to the notifications so every time the Sensor value is read, `notify()` is invoked which calls `update()` of each observer from the observer list.

**Concern:**

- In order to subscribe to multiple sensors (subjects) for notifications (observer), I should be having a fixed-size buffer inside the `Notification` class (trying to avoid dynamic allocation) that holds the active subjects in it, but how would I pass in however many subjects I want the observer to get notified for given I want to attach all at once inside a `Notification` constructor?

```c
static uint8_t constexpr observerMaxSize = 3;

class Observer;

class Subject 
{   
    uint8_t headIdx = 0;          // the max index till observers are populated in the buffer
    uint8_t tailIdx = 0;    
    public:
    virtual ~Subject() = default;
         
    Observer *observerList[observerMaxSize];
    void attach(Observer *obs);
    void detach(Observer *obs);
    void notify(Subject*);
};

class Subject;

class Observer 
{
    public:
    virtual ~Observer() = default;
    virtual void update(Subject*) = 0;
};

class SensorA : public Subject {

};

class Notification : public Observer {
    Subject &_sub;
    public:
    Notification(Subject &sub) : _sub(sub) {
       _sub.attach(this);    // subscribing "sub" for notifications, but how to have multiple subs attach "this"? 
    }

};

int main(void) {

   SensorA a;
   Notification ntf(a);

}
```

Comment: If you can add `Observer * prev` and/or `Observer * next` member-variables (or similar) to your `Observer` class, you could then use them to chain any number of `Observer` objects together into a linked-list, without requiring any memory allocations.   (Note that any given `Observer` object could only be part of a single linked-list at a time, though; unless you wanted to add multiple previous/next pointers to the Observer class)

Comment: how are we using these two pointers for linking the `Observer` objects into a linked list without dynamically allocating anything?

Comment: actually, you probably meant to say `Subject *prev` and `Subject *next` since `Observer` class needs to know how many `Subject` it's getting notified for, no? Also, how do you go about keeping track of all the subjects? for every new subject? do you also have a `current` pointer and a `head` pointer? how would that be different than a fixed-size buffer with indices?

Comment: Fixed size buffer has a maximum size; with linked lists there is no maximum size since each object brings with it it’s own space for pointer(s).

Comment: true, but how are you keeping track of the start of the subject without having a head pointer?

Comment: Use a head-pointer.

Comment: well...if an object that's in the middle of the "linked list" needs to be detached, how would you go about "removing it" such that it's no longer a part of the list while keeping in mind they are not dynamically allocated objects?

Comment: Same way you remove any object from the middle of a linked list:  `void RemoveThisObjectFromLinkedList() {if (prev) prev->next = this->next; if (next) next->prev = this->prev; this->prev = NULL; this->next = NULL;}`

Comment: Fair...but do you agree `Observer` class should have `Subject *prev` and `Subject *next` as opposed to `Observer` being the type so they'd be linking the chain of multiple `Subject`?

Comment: It's your program, design it the way that makes sense to you.  I have only the code in your question to go on, and so my understanding of how you want it to work is limited.

Comment: @Jazzy  I PERSONALLY would have the Subject have an `Observer *pHead;` as a member and each Observer have an `Observer *pNextObserver;` to point to the next one.    It does mean each Observer is specific to a Subject, but it's a bit of an odd pattern to observe multiple things at the same time with the same Observer.

Comment: um, curious tho whether it doesn't make sense to have `Subject *pHead`, `Subject *cur`, and perhaps `Subject *next` inside an `Observer` class since the `Notification` observer is expected to receive notifications from attached `Sensor` subjects...and these subjects would be passed into the constructor of `Notification`?

Comment: @Jazzy  Depends on if you want multiple observers per sensor, or multiple sensors per observer, or both.      If its multiple sensors per observer, then you can just have the OnEvent() pass in some sensor identifying information and install the same observer into all sensors(or have mini-observers that just forward the observation to a central collection point).    If its multiple observers for each sensor, then a linked list in the observer makes the most sense.   If its both, then probably a fixed array of connected observers in the Sensor makes the most sense.

Comment: multiple sensors (multiple subjects) subscribe to notifications (single observer). so I how I got around is to store the references to all these subjects in a buffer inside a `Notification` class and invoke `attach()` on each subject. If the user then wants to unsubscribe for any sensr notifcation, they would invoke `unsubscribe(Subject *sensor)` in an observer class itself, which iterates over the buffer and once the desired subject is matched, it invokes `detach()` on it